# How to access a particular child of jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have this table.

```html
<table id="mytable">
<tr>
  <td><input type="text"/></td>
  <td><input type="text"/></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="text"/></td>
  <td><input type="text"/></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now, I want to extract the user input from second text field but for only those rows which have checkbox checked. I am able to select and print the checkboxes that are checked using this jQuery code.

```js
var x = $('#mytable td input:checked');
$.each(x, function(key, value) {
  console.log(value)
});
```

I am not sure how to get the input field data from this object, I have tried using .children() but that resulted in error.I have very basic knowledge of jQuery. Please help.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xsfkexeb/2/

Comment: [`$(this).closest('td').prev().find('input').val()`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/jbtzbaz1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the tr with checked inputs then find the input in its second td like

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('#mytable tr:has(input:checked) td:nth-child(2) input').each(function() {
    snippet.log(this.value)
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button>Print</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to all who answered, This surely increased my understanding of selectors. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use has selector

```
$('#mytable td:has(input:checked)').find( "input[type='text']:last" ).each( function(){

   console.log($(this).val());

} );
```

Or may be simply prev() of parent() has mentioned above

```
$('#mytable td input:checked').each(function() {      
     console.log($(this).parent().prev().find("input").val());
});
```

Comment: `.last()` and `:last` returns a **single** element. Why `each` on it. Try to integrate in fiddle

Comment: @Tushar Sorry, i meant that `Use prev() like how Tushar has mentioned above`

Comment: No prob. Just wanted to tell you that the code was wrong.